# Android line-of-business app not deployed via Intune

Tags: android, mdm, intune

I'm trying to deploy an Android app that is only available as a .apk file to smartphones using Microsoft Intune.

The device is enrolled and it is part of a group. I have created an "Android line-of-business app" by uploading the .apk file and providing a name and description. I have then assigned the app to the group that the smartphones are in. Even after waiting a considerable amount of time, nothing has happened.

I have also created an a "Managed Google Play app" and assigned it to the same group. It was installed immediately.

Is there some setting I have to alter that I'm missing?